# Azure Web Sites environment detected ; keys will not be encrypted at rest - Dot Net Core 2.1 - Azure Web App

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have Deployed the Web App in Azure through Visual Studio.

I enabled the Logs in `logs/stdout`

Logged the following log:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      Azure Web Sites environment detected. Using 'D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: D:\home\site\wwwroot
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:7033
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://odataoneclient20170459.azurewebsites.net/  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 493.3555ms 404 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://odataoneclient20170459.azurewebsites.net/  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 5.9929ms 404 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://odataoneclient20170459.azurewebsites.net/  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 0.3737ms 404 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://odataoneclient20170459.azurewebsites.net/  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 1.1778ms 404
```

I want to know why this exception occurs, and what is the solution for it.

**i currently have OAuth 2.0 - Client ID, secret, and azure Mongo instance host and credentials in my appsettings.json file that is used in dot net core web project to connect.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not look like an exception, but more like a log entry. What it seems to be saying is probably because the DPAPI (Data Protection Application Programming Interface) is not available in the Azure Web App environment the keys will be left unencrypted. DPAPI is used on Windows to encrypt and store keys at rest.

Comment: so what action should i take to add DPAPI in Azure Web App

Comment: You can't add it to a web farm like environment e.g. Azure web apps. DPAPI is machine bound, so it will not be shared across a farm. Are you trying to use encryption at rest? In that case there are other ways to achieve this in Azure Web apps. Like using the Azure keyvault. [https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/issues/92]

Comment: i currently have OAuth 2.0 - Client ID, secret, and azure Mongo instance host and credentials in my appsettings.json file that is used in simple project to connect.

Comment: In that case, I’d suggest using the Azure keyvault for those credentials. Putting them in app settings in plaintext is risky.

Comment: It seems that the same message is connected to dropping all open WebSocket connections. Is it possible? How can I solve this issue?